# Acrobat JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat to create a form, and am using JavaScript to implement additional functionality. I can't find a description anywhere of the control classes for the form (for example, what are the member variables of a CheckBox?).

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

What I'm trying to do is modify the value in a TextBox based on the values in other TextBoxes and the checked status of corresponding CheckBoxes. If possible, could someone give me an idea of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Javascript documentation for Acrobat 10.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm)

You can set the value of a text field using code like:

```
this.getField("My Text Field").value = "New Value";
```